# Django: Controlling Admin URLs

Tags: django, django-admin

After not finding an answer, I'm wondering if it is possible to control the Admin url sequence. I have a Post model. When I go to list my Posts in admin, the url is localhost:8000/admin/posts/posts. Is there a way to use the localhost:8000/admin/posts url instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by defining the url directly in your own `urls.py` before you include the admin urls, but why do you need to do this? And how will you get to the list page at that point? Is there a real need here or is it simply a question of taste? If it's the latter, consider that while you may only have one model in your `posts` app at this time, you may want to extend the app later. And that stepping away from Django's conventions will make it more confusing to maintain.

Comment: Correct. It is a matter of taste. But since the admin will never be public, the issue is rather anal.